# Не все ветви кода возвращают значение

Tags: c#

> CS0161    "Program.Calculate(string, int, int)": не все ветви кода
>   возвращают
>   значение. ConsoleApp1 C:\Users\денис\source\repos\calculateoncsharp\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs

```
public static int Calculate(string action1, int a2, int a1)
{
    switch (action1){
        case "pi":
            return a1 + a2;
        case "mi":
            return a1 - a2;
        case "mu":
            return a1 * a2;
        case "de":
            return a1 / a2;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("Error");
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Все правильно в default: нет return

Comment: 1) либо в default пропишите return 2) либо после конструкции switch добавьте return 3) либо вместо return (в 1) или 2) ) кидайте исключение, если не знаете какое значение вернуть при отсутствии оператора

Comment: даже при отсутствие default выдает эту ошибку

Comment: Если не будет `default`, то не будет возврата, если ни под один `case` не подпало. Либо в `default` прописать `return`, либо в конце метода.

Answer (score 5):

Правильное решение - не возвращать какое-то *нейтральные* значение, а выбросить исключение:

```
public static int Calculate(string action1, int a2, int a1)
{
    switch (action1){
        case "pi":
            return a1 + a2;
        case "mi":
            return a1 - a2;
        case "mu":
            return a1 * a2;
        case "de":
            return a1 / a2;
        default:
            throw new ArgumentException();
    }
}
```

Перехватывать исключение и выводить сообщение об ошибке будет вызывающая сторона:

```
Console.WriteLine("Введите команду");
string action = Console.ReadLine();
try
{
    int z = Calculate(action, x, y);
}
catch (ArgumentException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Команда неверна!");
}
```

Comment: Писал схожий ответ, опередили. Хочу добавить, что не обязательно делать `return` или `throw` именно в `default`. Компилятор будет доволен, например, если сделать `return` или `throw` после `switch`. А то из всех ответов это не очевидно.

Comment: @4per, ну это - да. Обычно именно так и пишу (можно сэкономить строчку). Главное чтобы все возможные пути следования выполнения кода "упирались" в return или throw

Answer (score -2):

Метод в любом случае должен возвращает значение типа int. В ветке default ничего не возвращается, поэтому и ошибка.

Comment: Добавь в default return -1, как обозначение ошибки.

Comment: Ну вернули мы `-1` и как определить, нормальное это значение или нет? 2 минус 3 тоже равно -1

Comment: Согласен, поэтому при проектировании такие методы вообще не делают. Обычно на каждую операцию создают отдельный метод, даже если он однострочный. И тип int для таких вычислений не подойдет. Необходим double.

Answer (score -2):

В default надо возвращать какое-то значение типа int, которое возвращает функция

```
public static int Calculate(string action1, int a2, int a1)
    {
        switch (action1)
        {
            case "pi":
                return a1 + a2;

            case "mi":
                return a1 - a2;
            case "mu":
                return a1 * a2;
            case "de":
                return a1 / a2;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Error");
                return 1;
                //break;
        }
    }
```