# Функция арифметики

Tags: c#, строки, if, double

Задача: написать функцию, которая будет выполнять арифметические задачи (сложение, вычитание, умножение, деление), короче говоря - элементарнейшие действия в программировании.
Написал следующий код:

```
using System;

public class Kata 
{
  public static double Arithmetic(double a, double b, string op) 
  {
    double result = 0;
    
    if (op == "add")
    {
      result = a + b;
      return result;
    }
    else if (op == "subtract")
    {
      result = a - b;
      return result;
    }
    else if (op == "multiply")
    {
      result = a * b;
      return result;
    }
     else if (op == "divide")
    {
      result = a / b;
      return result;
    }
  }
}
```

Входными данными являются: переменные типа `double` `a` и `b`, и `string` `op`

Понимаю, что вопрос скорее смешной чем серьёзный, но я бы и не обращался, если бы всё заработало - вместо этого выдаёт ошибку:

> src/Solution.cs(5,24): error CS0161: 'Kata.Arithmetic(double, double, string)': not all code paths return a value

Что же пошло не так...

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса [Не все ветви кода возвращают значение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/792367/373567)

Comment: Ситуация аналогична, но отличие в том, что у того человека возникла эта же проблема в конструкции switch, а у меня в конструкции if. Может стоит в таком случае мне изменить название вопроса?

Comment: Семантически это одна и та же ошибка, способ ветвления кода при этом не важен. На ваше усмотрение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static double Arithmetic(double a, double b, string op) 
{
  double result = 0;

  if (op == "add")
    result = a + b;
  else if (op == "subtract")
    result = a - b;
  else if (op == "multiply")
    result = a * b;
  else if (op == "divide")
    result = a / b;

  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

В дополнение к ответу от @Igor, еще можно вот так:

```csharp
public static double Arithmetic(double a, double b, string op)
{
    double result = 0;
    switch(op)
    {
        case "add":
            result = a + b;
            break;
        case "substract":
            result = a - b;
            break;
        case "multiply":
            result = a * b;
            break;
        case "divide":
            result = a / b;
            break;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Или с помощью [нового синтаксиса](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#switch-expressions), доступного в C# 8.0:

```csharp
public static double Arithmetic(double a, double b, string op) => op switch
{
    "add" => a + b,
    "substract" => a - b,
    "multiply" => a * b,
    "divide" => a / b,
    _ => 0
};
```

Но лучше для значения "по умолчанию" не возвращать `0`, а бросить исключение

```
_ => throw new InvalidOperationException("Unknown arithmetic operation");
```