# Использование локальной переменной, которой не присвоено значение

Tags: c#

Так компилируется:

```
class Program
{
    delegate void Message();

    private static void GoodMooning()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Доброе утро");
    }

    private static void GoodEvening()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Добрый вечер");
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Message message;
        if(DateTime.Now.Hour < 12)
        {
            message = GoodMooning;
        }
        else 
        {
            message = GoodEvening;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.Hour);
        message();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }       
}
```

А вот так не компилируется и пишет, что переменная message не инициализирована:

```
class Program
{
    delegate void Message();

    private static void GoodMooning()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Доброе утро");
    }

    private static void GoodEvening()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Добрый вечер");
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Message message;
        int a = 2;
        if(a < 12)
        {
            message = GoodMooning;
        }
        message();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }       
}
```

Comment: Что произошло, почему вы сняли отметку с ответа?

Comment: наверное, случайно, извините

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если бы `a` была константой, скомпилировался бы.

```cs
const int a = 2;
```

А значения переменных - не во власти компилятора, потому что они определяются при запуске приложения, а не компиляции.

Компилятор просто не знает, какой будет результат выполнения условия, поэтому и предупреждает вас о том, что переменная не инициализирована. Вы можете это исправить.

```cs
Message message = null;
```

Либо можно вынести эту переменную в поле из метода, тогда она получит значение по умолчанию автоматически.

```cs
private static Message message;
```

Есть еще одно решение, если вы точно уверены, что условие выполнится при запуске приложения, можно успокоить компилятор бросив исключение. Вы как бы точно знаете, что оно не будет выброшено, а компилятор будет точно знать, что непроинициализированная переменная не будет использована - все довольны.

```cs
Message message;
int a = 2;
if (a < 12)
{
    message = GoodMooning;
}
else
    throw new Exception("Вот сейчас совсем неожиданно было");
message();
```

[Документация](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0165).

Comment: с null все понятно - если компилятор требует инициализацию - давайте-ка  быстро исполним желание компилятора. Мне непонятна суть, почему как вы утверждаете компилятор просто не знает, какой будет результат исполнения. Получается, что при наличии блока else он уже знает, каков будет результат и message будет проинициализирована?

Comment: интересный вариант

Comment: @Proshka компилятор ничего не знает о значениях переменных, ему не положено знать. Он только видит места, где они впервые присваиваются и используются. Задача компилятора уберечь вас от непредсказуемого поведения кода, только и всего. Я дополнил ответ.

Comment: @Proshka есть другая очень похожая ошибка компиляции, которая решается точно так же - [Не все ветви кода возвращают значение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/792377/373567).

Comment: прикольная штука, спасибо, пригодится точно.

Answer (score 2):

В первом варианте компилируется, потому что до вызова делегата, он в любом случае получает значение, а во втором варианте message получит значение только в случае если сработает условие `DateTime.Now.Hour < 12`, поэтому компиляция и не происходит. По идее, message можно просто проинициализировать `null` и код скомпилируется.

Comment: ок, если объявить интовую переменную вместо получения текущего времени и установить ее значение меньше, чем 12, все равно второй вариант не скомпилируется.

Comment: @ aepot это понятно. Вы пишете, что во втором варианте message получит значение в случае, если выполнится условие "текущее время меньше значения 12". Так переменную мы объявляем для того, чтобы условие в if выполнялось безусловно.

Comment: @aepot я хочу понять, где по мнению компилятора происходит инициализация message? Получается, что в инструкции, расположенной в блоке else

Comment: @aepot спасибо за обсуждение - разобрался

Answer (score -1):

По-моему, вот как работает CLR в данном случае. Вычисление значения текущего времени происходит позже, чем проверяется инициализация объекта делегата.
Почему? Потому что при установке явного значения if(true) - код компилируется без ошибок.

```
 class Program
{
    delegate void Message();

    private static void GoodMooning()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Доброе утро");
    }

    private static void GoodEvening()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Добрый вечер");
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Message message;
        if(true)
        {
            message = GoodMooning;
        }

        message();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: Это не похоже на ответ, вы не объяснили себе, почему он компилируется без ошибок :)